# Xtext, get Iselection Input in the LaunchMydslShortcut

Tags: eclipse, dsl, xtext, xtend

I'm trying to make a simple DSL with `Xtext` and execute it with an interpreter, the grammar is the initial *Hello Word* project.
I can can execute the `.Text` file successfully.
In the `org.xtext.example.mydsl.ui` project I write this in the `plugin.xml` file To run the Project from my class `LaunchMydslShortcut`.

```
  <extension
    point="org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchShortcuts">
 <shortcut
       class="org.xtext.example.mydsl.ui.MyDslExecutableExtensionFactory:org.xtext.example.mydsl.ui.launch.LaunchMydslShortcut"
       icon="icon/sample.gif"
       id="org.xtext.example.mydsl.u.launchMyDsl"
       label="MyDsll"
       modes="run">

       <contextualLaunch>
       <enablement>
         <with variable="selection">
           <count value="1"/>
           <iterate
                 ifEmpty="false"
                 operator="and">
              <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile"/>
                <test property="org.eclipse.debug.ui.matchesPattern"
                      value="*.mydsl"/>
           </iterate>
         </with>
       </enablement>
       <contextLabel
          mode="run"
          label="Run Mydsl"/>
     </contextualLaunch>

 </shortcut>
</extension>
```

This is my `LaunchMydslShortcut` class :

```
class LaunchMydslShortcut implements ILaunchShortcut {
    @Inject
    private IResourceForEditorInputFactory resourceFactory;

    override launch(ISelection selection, String mode) {
        println("launch from selection")

    }

    override launch(IEditorPart editor, String mode) {
        val input = editor.editorInput

        if (editor instanceof XtextEditor && input instanceof FileEditorInput) {
            val resource = resourceFactory.createResource(input)
            resource.load(newHashMap())
            println("launch Doooone")
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm expecting to use `launch(IEditorPart editor, String mode)` function, but it executes the `launch(ISelection selection, String mode)`.
so the question would be, what's the différence between the two? why my project is using the first? and how do I use the second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one `void launch(ISelection selection, String mode)` is called when you launch your generator from the package explorer for example.

The second one `void launch(IEditorPart editor, String mode)` is called when launching from an editor context menu.

You can use a Utility to get the input file you need and then create an IResource.

Good example is in `org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.launcher.WorkflowLaunchUtils.workflowFileFor(ISelection)` and `org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.launcher.WorkflowLaunchUtils.workflowFileFor(IEditorPart)` it works with mwe2 files but it is easy to adopt it for your DSL.

Comment: Here is a github repo link: https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-eclipse/blob/master/org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.ui/src/org/eclipse/xtext/xtext/launcher/WorkflowLaunchUtils.java